# Condition on group\ring that satisfies solutions for 'linear equations'

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

let $R$ be a ring. Suppose the ring satisfies the property that for every equation of the form $kx=r$ there is a solution in $R$ (where $k\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ and $r\in R$). The question is about the additive group structure rather than its multiplicative structure, so the question can be essentially asked regarding groups. Nontheless, my question is, is there a condition on groups\rings that satisfies this condition, or rather something equivalent to it?

Comment: Divisible groups.

Comment: Perfect! thank you @Randall, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Randall Thank you for making that a solution!

Comment: The condition $k \neq 0$ is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For abelian groups (which should satisfy your needs since you care about the additive structure of a ring), this concept is that of [*divisible group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group).  This is closely related to injectivity of modules, and has been studied since circa 1955.